# URL Rewrite and $_POST

Tags: php, post, url-rewriting

So im trying to rewrite my url.

I am under IIS (godaddy.com)
I use a web.config file to write my rules.

So right now i have the basic rewrite rule working

```
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Working means that if i type mydomain.com/article/2016/rewrite in the adresse bar it is redirecting me to index.php.

However once on index.php i cant retrieve the value of id and title using

```
 $_POST['id'];
 $_POST['title'];
```

`$_GET` is working but how do i get it to work with `$_POST`?

Thanks.

Comment: $_GET is working but why is $_POST not working? I would rather post content then get it

Answer (score 1):

Data in the URL is placed in `$_GET`. If you want data in `$_POST` then you have to put it in the request body when you make the request. URL rewriting can't copy data there.